# Laravel : Issue in database connection when use # keyword in env file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

When use # keyword in env file like below

```
DB_PASSWORD=&#252525
```

Database connection not happening in laravel, As in config/database.php file we just have password = & instead of full string

How can we resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

Laravel consider # as a comment in environment file. So write in quotes If any text has # value in the text in environment file.

```
DB_PASSWORD='&#252525'
```